# Scala Some, None and my custom Default

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

We have Some, None in Scala and I need the third one named Default.
The idea behind is:

- Some means there is some value
- None means no value at all. Do not use value.
- Default (my custom thing) means user wants me to apply some built in defaults.

  It should act like None (i.e. compatible with Option) and I'll treat Default in a special way in my routines.
  I had a look at: [Scala: Something like Option (Some, None) but with three states: Some, None, Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738062/scala-something-like-option-some-none-but-with-three-states-some-none-unk)

I don't want to completely "shadow" Some, None with my custom types. I want let user use them and apply my own "Default" at certain cases.

@Michael Zajac gave several options, I think the frist one is pretty good.

I can have built in Some, None and "artificial" like

```
case object DefaultParamHere {
    def apply(): Option[String] = {
      Some("Substitute me we default framework value, please")
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

so use case will be:

```
case class Application(artifact: Artifact,
                              mainClass: Class[_],
                              jvmMemory: Option[Memory] = None,
                              jvmOpts: Option[String] = DefaultParamHere(),
                              applicationConfiguration: List[String] = Nil) extends Stage
```

Comment: Who are your users? Programmers? Why not use `getOrElse(myDefault)`?

Comment: `Option` is sealed, so you cannot extend it. Maybe you should build another layer, i.e. another wrapper class

Comment: @RaphaelRoth sure, I can't and looking for other approaches.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov what do you mean by getOrElse? My users are developers. And they should tell me: use my (user) value, do not use any value or do something good for me (user sets Default)

Comment: You can have a method taking a `def foo[T](default: T)` and use that as a fallback for your `Option[T]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a several options, really. You could:

**Use a sentinel value.** For example, if you're working with `Option[Int]`, `Some(-1)` could encode the "default" but not `None` value. Client code would need to know this value needs to be handled specially, which makes this solution weak. It's easy to implement, but difficult for those that need to use code that returns sentinel values. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

**Use a different type**, such as `Option[Either[Default, B]]`. In this solution, `Some(Right(a))` would represent an existing value, `Some(Left(Default))` would represent your special case, and `None` would still represent the lack of data entirely. `Default` could be as simple as a case object that signals something you need to do, or some sort of data type that contains default values the program may need to deal with. In my opinion, this is the best option (*pun intended*), as it makes it clear exactly what a method may be returning when returning this type, and it forces code to deal with the `Default` case.

**Use a different type**, such as `Option[Option[A]]`. Here `Some(Some(a))` would represent an existing value, `Some(None)` could represent your special case, and `None` the same as before. This is *similar* to the previous solution, except that there would not be a way to encode additional information within the default case, and it would be a little more cryptic as to what a method returning this type was actually meant for.

**Use a different type**, such as [`scalaz.Either3`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.11/7.2.7/index.html#scalaz.Either3). Similarly to the previous two solutions, you could encode your three cases using `Either3[None, Default, A]`, where `Right3(a)`, `Middle3(Default)`, and `Left3(None)` would be the respective cases. This again would make it clear what the type is intended for and force client code to deal with all three cases. However, it is likely overkill for what you need. Still, if you ever wanted to encode more information within the `None` case, `Either3` is always out there.

**Use a wrapper.** It's difficult to say exactly what this would look like without knowing more about your use-case, but you could make a simple class that wraps `Option` and can supply the default you want.

```
case class Option3[A](opt: Option[A], default: A) {
  def getOrDefault: A = opt.getOrElse(default)
}
```

This of course, is probably not what you want exactly, but something along these lines. You could also provide an implicit conversion from your wrapper to `Option` that can substitute a default value in `None` cases, or otherwise, depending on what you really want it to do.

Comment: *Use a sentinel value.* is a good thing. I can imitate these default values. I can do smth like case Object {def apply={Some(-1)}} which is good tradeoff I think... The solutions seem to me too complex. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @Sergey They seem complex until someone forgets what the sentinel value is, then they introduce bugs that may be difficult to fix. That's the trade-off.